# i bought/ have bought is before

Tags: tense

If someone suggested, ‘You try to buy this.’

Then I answered, ‘I have bought it before.’ or ‘ I bought it before.’

before use past tense or present perfect tense?

Comment: I think there's not really that much difference.

Comment: thanks!! ☺️ both ok? where are u living?

Comment: Yes, uh somewhere in asia.

Comment: I doubt I'd even get to the response because the question is so weird. What happens if you fail when you tried to buy it?